# Probability in Discrete Maths

Tags: probability

> One side of a $6$-sided die is marked $0$, two sides are marked $2$, and three sides are marked $3$. Each side is equally likely to occur when the die is rolled. The die is rolled twice and the results are recorded.
>
> Let $A$ be the event that the first roll is $0$.
>
> Let $B$ be the event that the second roll is $3$.
>
> Let $C$ be the event that the sum of the two rolls is $5$.
>
> (a) Find $Pr(A)$, $Pr(B)$, and $Pr(C)$.
>
> (b) Find $Pr(A \cap B)$, $Pr(A \cap C)$, and $Pr(B \cap C)$.
>
> (c) Are $A$ and $C$ independent events? Are $B$ and $C$ independent events?
>
> (d) Find $Pr(A \cup C)$ and $Pr(B \cup C)$.
>
> (e) Find $Pr(B|(B \cup C))$.

My answers:

a) $Pr(A)= \frac 14$, $Pr(B)= \frac 38$, $Pr(C)= \frac 14$

b) $Pr(A\cap B)= \frac 18$, $Pr(A\cap C)= 0$, $Pr(B\cap C)= \frac 18$

c) No for both

d) $Pr(A\cup C)= \frac 12$, $Pr(B\cup C)= \frac 12$

e) This part I am not sure?

I am afraid my answers may not be right? Could I have some assistance please. Thanks.

Comment: Surely $Pr(B)=\frac 12$, as the probability of rolling a $3$ is $\frac 36=\frac 12$. The fact it is the second roll has no bearing on it, as rolls are independant of each other

Comment: Also, $Pr(C)=\frac 13$. See the table below: \begin{array}{c|cccccc}&0&2&2&3&3&3\\\hline
0&0&2&2&3&3&3\\
2&2&4&4&5&5&5\\
2&2&4&4&5&5&5\\
3&3&5&5&6&6&6\\
3&3&5&5&6&6&6\\
3&3&5&5&6&6&6\\\end{array}
We can count up the number of $5$ values, to get
$Pr(C)=\frac{12}{36} = \frac 13$

Comment: Finally, $Pr(A)=\frac 16$

Answer (score 3):

I've turned this from a comment into an answer to further explain my points.

Your answers to part (a) are incorrect.

First we look at $Pr(A)=Pr(\text{first roll is $0$})$

We can treat this dice as a regular $6$-sided dice, with the probability of each side coming up being $\frac 16$.

As there is only $1$ zero on the dice, the probability of rolling a $0$ is $\frac 16$, so we have $$Pr(A)=\frac 16$$

Next we look at $Pr(B)=Pr(\text{second roll is $3$})$

There are three sides, out of the total of $6$ which have a three on them. It doesn't matter that this is the second roll, the outcome of the first roll will not alter the outcome of the second roll - the dice can't remember what it rolled previously!

Therefore, we have $$Pr(B)=\frac 36 = \frac 12$$

Finally, look at $Pr(C)=Pr(\text{the sum of the two rolls is $5$})$

We can draw this up as a table

\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}\hline&0&2&2&3&3&3\\\hline
0&0&2&2&3&3&3\\
2&2&4&4&\color{red}5&\color{red}5&\color{red}5\\
2&2&4&4&\color{red}5&\color{red}5&\color{red}5\\
3&3&\color{red}5&\color{red}5&6&6&6\\
3&3&\color{red}5&\color{red}5&6&6&6\\
3&3&\color{red}5&\color{red}5&6&6&6\\\hline\end{array}

We can count up how many of the results were $5$, giving us the answer $$Pr(C)=\frac{12}{36}=\frac 13$$

Hopefully this clears up some things, and maybe now you can try the other parts of the question again

Comment: ah i had that in my mind , but i wrote down the sample space and got few things mixed up . thanks you !

Comment: but is there any sample space for this part ?

Comment: is pr(AnB)= 1/12 , pr(AnC)= 0 , pr(BnC)=1/6

Comment: @DaveKumar Yes, $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)=\frac16\times \frac 12 = \frac1{12}$

Comment: @DaveKumar And yes, the other two are correct too

Comment: Thank you but the last part which is [pr(B) n pr(B u C)] / pr(BuC) . does that equal to 1/2 . if not hw di approach because i don't know whether they are independent or not ?

Comment: I'm afraid you're getting to the edge of my knowledge :/ Not sure I'm the best person to help there